# Alpha vantage - how to get SMA of a stock for specific date

Tags: alpha-vantage

I need to Know the query to fetch SMA of a stock for a specific date range.

I don't see anything about data range in API document.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but decided to go with IEXFinance instead. It doesn't seem like Alpha Advantage is quite there yet. As you can see from the screenshot, they understood the importance of this feature and made it extremely simple. No API key or anything needed too, which is nice.[Directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXq82.png)

Comment: IEXFinance doesn't support NSE India stocks. Thanks for your suggestions